# Android animation with sets

Tags: android, xml, animation, mobile, set

I have an animation like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"
    android:fillAfter="true" >
<translate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="600"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="10"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="-500" />

    </set>
```

And it works fantastic, however this is not all I want to do, I want the view to go up and then to go back down. To accomplish this I then change the animation to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"
    android:fillAfter="true" >
<translate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="600"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="10"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="-500" />
    <translate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="600"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXDelta="10"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="500" />

    </set>
```

However then it doesn't work. I would like one animation to exevute after the other, however I am guessing that they are both executing at the same time. In this case I simply need to be able to do the opposite of the first animation, however I would like to know how to do a scale after a translate and so on. Do I need two separate animations? What is the correct way to run animations after each other instead of all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second animation in the set, you want to offset the animation so that it starts after the first one. You can do this by using the offset attribute: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:startOffset

```
<translate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="600"

    android:startOffset="600"

    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="10"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="500" />
```